Live activity is not getting create by remote notification in flutter
static void startLiveActivity(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      print("initialize liive");
      var liveActivitiesPlugin = LiveActivities();
      await liveActivitiesPlugin.init(
        appGroupId: 'group.coun366.WaterQualityLA',
      );
      print("after iniitiialize live");
      print("inside the liveactivity in try");
      final liveActivityModel = LiveActivityWQModel(
        appLogo: LiveActivityImageFromAsset('assets/icon.jpeg'),
        appNameLogo: LiveActivityImageFromAsset('assets/newLogo.png'),
        title: message.notification?.title ?? "DO LOW",
        pondId: message.data['pondId'] ?? "Unknown Pond ID",
        pondName: message.data['pondName'] ?? "Unknown Pond Name",
      );
      print("before end activiities");

      print("before activityId");

      final activityId =
          await liveActivitiesPlugin.createActivity(liveActivityModel.toMap());
      print('Live Activity started with ID: $activityId');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to start Live Activity: $e');
    }
  }

I am calling this startLiveActivity function in my notification file whose code is given below.
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:live_activities/live_activities.dart';
import 'package:live_activities/models/live_activity_image.dart';

import '../Models/LiveActivity/live_activity_wq_model.dart';

class LocalNotificationService {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize() {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: true,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: true,
      provisional: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher"),
      iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
    );

    _notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  static void createAndDisplayNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
      NotificationDetails notificationDetails;

      message.data['isAlarm']?.toString() == "true"
          ? notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                "AquagenixProPriority",
                "AquagenixProChennalPriority",
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,
                sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(
                    message.notification?.android?.sound),
              ),
              iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
                presentSound: true,
                sound: message.notification?.apple?.sound?.name,
              ),
            )
          : notificationDetails = const NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                "AquagenixPro",
                "AquagenixProChennal",
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,
              ),
              iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(),
            );

      await _notificationsPlugin.show(
        id,
        message.notification!.title,
        message.notification!.body,
        notificationDetails,
      );

      startLiveActivity(message);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  static void startLiveActivity(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      print("initialize liive");
      var liveActivitiesPlugin = LiveActivities();
      await liveActivitiesPlugin.init(
        appGroupId: 'group.coun366.WaterQualityLA',
      );
      print("after iniitiialize live");
      print("inside the liveactivity in try");
      final liveActivityModel = LiveActivityWQModel(
        appLogo: LiveActivityImageFromAsset('assets/icon.jpeg'),
        appNameLogo: LiveActivityImageFromAsset('assets/newLogo.png'),
        title: message.notification?.title ?? "DO LOW",
        pondId: message.data['pondId'] ?? "Unknown Pond ID",
        pondName: message.data['pondName'] ?? "Unknown Pond Name",
      );
      print("before end activiities");

      print("before activityId");

      final activityId =
          await liveActivitiesPlugin.createActivity(liveActivityModel.toMap());
      print('Live Activity started with ID: $activityId');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to start Live Activity: $e');
    }
  }


}

I am getting issue that when my app is open and notification comes from server my live activity gets created and come on lock screen but when I kill the app and notification comes my live activity did not get create and not even come on lock screen.And I am calling notification file in my main.dart file.I am using live activity package
I have tested the app in foreground and send the push notification then activity are created but when i killed the app and send push notification then it's not create even i checked with flutter logs command
